# Why is my water heater emitting cold water?

Tags: plumbing, water-heater

The water heater has one hose connection for the cold water (R) that comes from the street; I attach one end of the hose to the water heater and the other end to the spout on the wall that brings city water into the house (right side-cold water).

The water heater has a second hose connection (L) where that cold water would now be coming out hot; I attach a second hose there, and the other end to the pipe that feeds the water to the whole house (L).

The problem is that *that* pipe (L) that is supposed to receive the now hot water from the water heater and shoot it into the faucets of the house is shooting cold water out with pressure.

[image]

Comment: What is the brand/model of the hot water heater? I think that RDMan's answer is on to something - this header may be designed for a _single faucet_ not the _whole house_.  Also, any clues on where the other copper pipe goes?

Answer (score 0):

The valve marked in blue is ( as I understand from you.) the cold water you use into the water heater.

The valve marked in yellow is what you are attempting to attach the hot water line from the water heater to.

The problem is, that I believe what you have is a single site water heater. It is used to provide hot water to a single faucet.

You are attempting to attach the outlet from the heater to a valve and have it provide hot water to the whole unit (home, office, etc.)  that is not possible.

Things are compounded by the fact that the valve in yellow is under pressure and is fed from another part of your plumbing system. ( There is another area where you have a water heater or a loop that would be cut to add a water heater, or there was a water heater and it was bypassed.)

Not knowing the entire system you have I cannot comment on how to achieve the results you want. However I can say with much certainty that what you are trying will not work.
[image]

It may be time to call a plumber.